# Deleting Certain Times VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was hoping someone could help me with a solution to this issue. I am trying to remove any values between 00:00:00 - 22:59:59 on VBA.

I've separated the time from the date using:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(RC[1],8)"
```

This leaves me with 00:27:37, for example.

I've searched for an answer quite a bit, but cannot find an adequate solution. I tried using the following but it did not work:

```
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "B")) And _
     Cells(i, "B").Value2 < TimeSerial(23, 0, 0) And _
     Cells(i, "B").Value2 <> "" Then
       Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `=RIGHT(RC[1],8)` returns a string! `00:27:37` then is not numeric...

Comment: it did not do anything to the data. @pnuts
Ah that would make sense DirkReichel .. I will try to work on this further. Any solutions to remove certain timestamps?

Comment: Well, it leaves you every values which start with `23` (from `23:00:00` to `23:59:59`). Is it hard to check if a string starts with `23`?

Comment: @pnuts well, `23abcdef` would still not be "*between 00:00:00 and 22:59:59*", would it? But yeah, you're right, I simply assumed OP only had times here

Answer (score 2):

Pnuts suggestion of *1 after =RIGHT formula has made the formula at the bottom work correctly.

Thank you, see below for solution.

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(RC[1],8)*1"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Dim lr As Long, i As Long

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr To 1 Step -1
 If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "B")) And _
 Cells(i, "B").Value2 < TimeSerial(23, 0, 0) And _
 Cells(i, "B").Value2 <> "" Then
   Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
 End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Dates and times in Excel are numerical value, whereby the date is respresented as a whole number (# of days since 01-Jan-1900), the time is represented as a  fractional part of a number, ranging between 0 (00:00) and < 1 (24:00)

So you can isolate the time of a combined date/time value by

```
vTime = vDateTime - Int(vDateTime)
```

Then, the time you look for is >= 23:00 which in numeric terms is >= 23/24

Example:

```
Sub Find23()
Dim vTime As Date, vDateTime As Date

    vDateTime = #7/17/2018 11:00:00 PM#
    Debug.Print vDateTime

    vTime = vDateTime - Int(vDateTime)
    Debug.Print vTime

    If vTime >= 23 / 24 Then
        Debug.Print "it was late in the evening ..."
        ' do your stuff here
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I have to point out that today is 43,298 so as far as VBA is concerned, it's not an integer (signed short integer with a maximum positive value of 32,767).

Comment: what I mean was not Integer as a number format (true: max is 32k) but integer as a "whole" number not containing a fractional part

Comment: Yes, in EN-US we use a comma like that to express forty-three thousand, two hundred and ninety-eight. In any event, today is larger tan a VBA 'integer'.

Comment: I know, it's confusing and more so to a neophyte. Perhaps 'whole number' might be better.

Comment: well ... this was intended to give an idea how to calculate the condition numerically rather than jumping thru string operations ... if you have a well formated date/time (i.e. as a numeric), string operations are definitely not a good strategy - me thinks

Comment: How about use `vTime = timevalue(vDateTime)`, instead of `vTime = vDateTime - Int(vDateTime)`.

Comment: @PaichengWu yes this would work, however the VBA doc speaks of mainly a "string" argument to `TimeValue()` and doesn't explicitely allow a DateTime as argument ... and then it's also to illustrate how easy and elegant you can use DateTimes in numeric calculations

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>I am trying to remove any values between 00:00:00 - 22:59:59 on VBA.</sub>

Wouldn't it be easier to keep data with an hour of 23?

```
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "B")) and not isempty(Cells(i, "B")) then
        if hour(Cells(i, "B").Value2) <> 23 then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next i
```